# send email with spring boot from localhost

Tags: email, spring-boot, smtp

I want to send email from localhost(mac or linux) to somewhere (let's say to several gmail addresses). Only send email, never receive email, like a notification push system.

I know mac/linux has a "sendmail" program, but now I need to send email with spring boot release 2.0.

On my mac:

`$ which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail`

I read through the spring boot email tutorial here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email, and did the similar configuration in my code, but it did not work. In the tutorial, the "host" of mailsendr is "smtp.gmail.com", in this case I need the the "host" be localhost (the machine which my spring boot app will run on).

Here is my email configuration in application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

The spring boot throw below error when sending email by the JavaMailSender(autowired):

`org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout 5000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout 5000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:446) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:321) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:310) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.gem.service.EmailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ibm.gem.component.ApplicationStartup.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartup.java:39) [classes/:na]
    at com.ibm.gem.component.ApplicationStartup.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartup.java:1) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.gem.PerfInsightApplication.main(PerfInsightApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout 5000
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:515) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:435) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.sun.mail.util.WriteTimeoutSocket.connect(WriteTimeoutSocket.java:115) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:351) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:239) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:1.6.1]
    ... 25 common frames omitted`

I think my configuration in application.properties is wrong, but I don't know what is the correct configuration. The mac/linux don't have built-in smtp server, do they? I don't know, and I don't want to install one. I just want the similar function like the "sendmail" program. When using the "sendmail" program, you don't need to specify the protocol, the port, ssl etc parameters, I don't know why I have to provide these information when using spring boot, and I don't know how to find these information on my computer.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved.

Turned out the mac(and most linux systems I believe) comes with a pre-installed mail system [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/). You need to start the mail system (which includes a smtp server) before you send email with spring boot.

Use below commands to start and check postfix status:

`$ sudo postfix status
$ sudo postfix start`

On mac, I use below command to check if smtp is running:

`$ sudo lsof -i :smtp
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
master    84359     root   13u  IPv4 0xacc57a372acc10b      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
master    84359     root   14u  IPv6 0xacc57a379b3eb63      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
postscree 84562 _postfix    6u  IPv4 0xacc57a372acc10b      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
postscree 84562 _postfix    7u  IPv6 0xacc57a379b3eb63      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)`

And in spring boot application.properties, I just need one line configuration:

`spring.mail.host=localhost`

It worked!

Comment: I'm confused , shouldn't we still be able to connect to the smtp.gmail.com host anyway from local? what if I want to deploy this App to AWS and send emails from the spring boot app? How can I know it works locally ??

Comment: @ennth if you want to send email from your gmail address, you need to connect to  gmail smtp server of course. My post is how to send email from local host.